# Flutter | Dio Package ... downloading Large Files in Background

Tags: flutter, download, flutter-dependencies, dio

I am using flutter with dio package to download files like powerpoint and videos ...etc

what i want to ask is how to download large file in background

```
try {
    await dio.download(
        fileURL, '$dir/$fileName.pptx',
        onReceiveProgress: showDownloadProgress,
        deleteOnError: true);
    print("BBBB");

    openDownloadedFile = '$dir/$fileName.pptx';
    print("CCCC");
  } on DioError catch(e) {
    print("11");

    final file = File('$dir/$fileName.pptx');
    file.deleteSync(recursive: true);
    if(e.response != null) {
      print("22");

      print(e.response.data);
      print(e.response.headers);
      print(e.response.request);
    } else{

      // Something happened in setting up or sending the request that triggered an Error
      print(e.request);
      print(e.message);
    }
  }
```

Best Regard

Comment: Same issue , any updates?

Comment: any updates you found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question has been asked, there is official support in Flutter for Background Tasks. You may want to check that out now.

Docs Link: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes

Example Link: https://flutteragency.com/schedule-background-tasks/

Complete Example (from the docs)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'WebSocket Demo';
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: title,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
  });

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  final _channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse('wss://echo.websocket.events'),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Form(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Send a message'),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 24),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: _channel.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : '');
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _sendMessage,
        tooltip: 'Send message',
        child: const Icon(Icons.send),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  void _sendMessage() {
    if (_controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      _channel.sink.add(_controller.text);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _channel.sink.close();
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use the [Flutter Downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) plugin to download large files as it uses the native download manager. Dio is more suited for downloading small files while the app is open.

Comment: I am building a comics app and want to download chapters (list of images) in the background. `Flutter Downloader` is not optimized to download a batch of files and I cannot fetch the image urls of every single chapter before triggering the download in the background. How do you suggest that I tackle this problem?

Comment: @SalaheddineNaoushi I would run dio in a background isolate. See: https://dart.dev/guides/language/concurrency#background-workers